# Allow normal behavior after defining command in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Normally, clicking the Media key "Play/Pause" in my keyboard plays/pauses the active YouTube video, as it should.
Now, I am developing a Google Chrome extension where I want to add some extra functionality after clicking this Media key, but without interfering with what it actual does. So it should still play/pause the video AND do my thing(before or after, it doesn't matter).

After loading my extension, if I click the Media key, I get the log(see code below) all right, but it no longer plays/pauses the YouTube video. It's like me defining the command consumes the event all together.

I'm defining the command in the manifest.json like this

```
"commands": {
      "play-pause": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "MediaPlayPause",
          "mac": "MediaPlayPause"
        },
        "description": "Play/Pause audio",
        "global": true
      }
}
```

and I have in my background.js script, just to see if I get the command(which I do)

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    console.log('Command:', command);
});
```

Any ideas on how to go about this, without having to write my own code for playing/pausing the video?

Comment: Remove suggested_key and let the user set/customize it in chrome://extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm just tried this but again, as soon as I bind the command with the Media key, it stops working for the rest of Chrome except for my extension.

Comment: Then it's just the way it is. Chrome gives priority to extensions.